# Auto-wiring issues with spring security & SAML

Tags: spring, spring-security, autowired, spring-saml

I'm trying to implement the spring-security and spring-saml modules in my project but facing the following error related to auto-wiring that fails.

(My Spring core & security jars are all 3.1.2 and the spring-saml jar is 1.0.0.)

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 52 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setWebSSOprofile(org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
... 60 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:952)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:821)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
... 62 more
```

I checked my autoscan related setting in the security.xml that I created and it is set to 
`<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security" />`
Which i think is pretty standard, but since I thought it might be better to autoscan on all dependent classes & second-guessing of course, I changed it to 
`<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework" />`

But on doing that I got a different error -

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration.asyncAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @EnableAsync annotation metadata was not injected
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
... 26 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @EnableAsync annotation metadata was not injected
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration.asyncAdvisor(ProxyAsyncConfiguration.java:45)
at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dbf0f346.CGLIB$asyncAdvisor$0(<generated>)
at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dbf0f346$$FastClassByCGLIB$$4c1b9c21.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dbf0f346.asyncAdvisor(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
... 27 more
```

My application utilizes an additonal context file & now i've added the security one also.

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/MbsOutContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml
    </param-value>
```

Can you let me know what I need to do to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem.  The solution was renaming the "webSSOProfile" bean to "webSSOprofile" (note lowercase P).  After I did that, it started up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your beans (`@Component, @Service, @Controller, ...`) are really located in the package `org.springframework.security`?

The scanning feature of spring detects "custom" beans automatically and register corresponding `BeanDefinitions` with the `ApplicationContext`. It is not intended for scanning the framework itself for any kind of bootstrapping.

Therefore this configuration should more look like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

You can find more information in the reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s10.html

Comment: I am using the spring security & SAML extension so I'm not quite sure if it is part of the Spring framework's core jars. The SAML documentation does show the configuration of the beans in the same way. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-integration.html#configuration-integration-bean-definitions